# Prevent network access with IPTables

Tags: networking, iptables

I try to block the user `sandbox` from accessing the network with this command:

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner sandbox -j DROP
```

However, after that I'm still able to ping an external host:

```
$ sudo -u sandbox ping 206.190.36.45
PING 206.190.36.45 (206.190.36.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 206.190.36.45: icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=802 ms
64 bytes from 206.190.36.45: icmp_req=2 ttl=49 time=791 ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

My configuration looks like this:

```
$ /sbin/iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match sandbox
```

#### Update

Apparently `ping` has `setuid root` set. I just had to remove it:

```
chmod u-s /bin/ping
```

Comment: looks like it works for TCP and UDP, but ICMP gets through.

Comment: Share your whole ruleset. Perhaps an earlier rule grants access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ping` is setuid root on your system, it is `root` which opens the socket from which `ping` sends its ICMP echo requests. Thus the rule will never match.

(Note that this is true on EL6, Debian squeeze, etc. More recent distributions have removed ping's setuid bit and replaced it with a capability. In these cases, the rule might match.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you have the nessesary iptable module loaded?

Try

```
modprobe ipt_owner
```

on the console.

Comment: `modprobe ipt_owner` exits without any output